# Prime numbers and $\{0\}$ are only subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$ inducing a group of symmetries $\sigma f = f\sigma$, $f = XY + Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $V$ be a subset of numbers of $\Bbb{Z}$, and $P$ be the primes.  Define the subset $A_f \subset S_V$ associated to $f=XY+Z$ to be

$A_f(V) = \{\sigma \in S_V: \sigma f(a,b,c) = f(\sigma a, \sigma b, \sigma c), \forall (a,b,c, f(a,b,c) )\in V^4\},$

where $S_V = $ the group of permutations of $V$.

Then $A_f(V)$ is a group if and only if $V = P$.

In the other thread that got downvoted.  It was never proven that just any $V$ induces a group structure.

Is this is known conjecture?  Reference please.

Look at this as an example but no where near proof:
$$
\begin{matrix}
3\cdot 7 + 2 &= 23 \\
& \uparrow h \\
7\cdot 2 + 3 &= 17 \\
& \uparrow h \\
2\cdot 3 + 7 &= 13 \\
& \downarrow g \\
2\cdot 3 + 5 &= 11 \\
& \downarrow g \\
5\cdot 2 + 3 &= 13 \\
& \downarrow g \\
3\cdot 5 + 2 &= 17
\end{matrix}
$$
Here $h =$ the cycle $(2,3,7)$ and $g = (2,3,5)$.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the primes here. You should start with some examples in the simplest case.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't understand why you think you don't need the primes.  I've had other threads with examples and people didn't take kindly to them.  I will try again to prove that just any set induces a group.  I'll make edits to post.

Comment: And your definition of $A_f(V)$ is unclear. 30min ago you were restricting to the case $a,b,c,f(a,b,c)$ are primes

Comment: I don't want to seem nit-picky, but $f=f(X,Y,Z)$ doesn't make any sense. $f$ is a function, while $f(X,Y,Z)$ is just a number (in this case, by definition, $XY+Z$).

Comment: @vrugtehagel that's called notational abuse.  Happens all day

Comment: @user1952009's initial comment seems to have been exactly right: starting with examples in the simplest possible cases in fact leads to the answer, and there's nothing even slightly related to primes in that answer. Sometimes commenters really *are* worth listening to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the revised conjecture is false.

Let $V = \{0, 1\}$.

There are only two permutations of $V$. Let's check that the nontrivial permutation $0 \leftrightarrow_{\sigma} 1$ does not preserve $f$. Well,

$$
f(1,1,0) = 1\cdot 1 + 0 = 1
$$
but
$$
f(\sigma 1, \sigma 1, \sigma 0) = f(0, 0, 1) = 1 
$$
rather than $0$, as required by the condition on $A_f$. So for this set, $A_f$ consists of only the identity permutation, and hence $A_f$ is a group.

In other words: there's another set of integers for which $A_f$ is a group, but it ain't the primes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's a known conjecture, but it sure seems like a false one.

For instance, for $V = \{0\}$, $S_V$ has a single element (the identity), and that element is in $A_f$, so $A_f$ is a trivial group. Hence $A_f$ *can* be a group without $V$ being the set of primes.

Comment: I upvote because the OP needs to understand the trivial group is the 1st obvious thing we see from his posts

Comment: Yeah...I didn't even consider the "if" part of the claim, where if $V = P$, we have $A_f$ is a group, because it seemed so much easier to falsify the "only if" part.

Comment: Dude, obviously I mean $V = P $ or $V = 0$ !!!

Comment: Then maybe you should have said so in the header?

Comment: Not obvious at all; indeed, looking at your 'example', it's not even clear that you know what a permutation of the integers is, so why would I think that you know how to formulate a conjecture clearly? Anyhow, now that this is a chameleon question, I'm outta here. Best of luck.